# How to check if the screen hasn't been clicked in Android?

Tags: java, android, touch-event

I know that if you want to check if someone clicked on something, you would do

```
if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
```

But I want to check if the screen hasn't been clicked at all.
What is the code I would produce in order to do this?

Also, as a side note, would it be a good idea to have all the classes in an Android app extend the `View` classes?

Comment: I wish i could vote both the answers down as they do not answer the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `boolean` variable called `istouched` and use `onTouchLisener` on your top most `View` actually its a `Window` that's where your `View`s are, quick sample

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                // i have been touched
                istouched = true;
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "you touched me?!! - i will tell my mom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                // you can implement this
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "shhh; i am touching", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

so the logic here is if `istouched` is `false` <strike>your device is not telling her mom</strike>, which means it has not being touched..

hope it helps

Comment: what does the boolean istouched have in it?

Comment: lol,Well, i hope you will, (: .. Sir,the `istouched` boolean is what i told you create in the description, so is an instance variable in your `Activity` class, by default its false.. btw, a little upvote might also be appreciated (: @PaulTrueman

Comment: thats all that should be in it? it just returns false?

Comment: Yea, by logic the `istouched` boolean will let you know if the screen has been touched, if not it is `false`, once its  touched it will `return true`, the `return false` at the end of the `touchListener` is one of those unreachables since `ACTION_DOWN` `returns true` hope you know that, you okay now@PaulTrueman

Comment: ah ok. Sorry just been working on this app for a while. My brain is flustered

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add  `android:onClick="method"` to the root layout in your layout xml.

in the method you can change a `boolean` variable to true (screenClicked = true).

Comment: also you can just create an onClickListener.. but i prefer the first way