# Effective use of touch/hover co-ordinates on a View

Tags: android, operating-system, screen, coordinate

On Android phone, I get the information of co-ordinates that, user touch on his/her phone screen or device. How do i then, use/pass these X-Y coordinates to run a specific function of mine, and use it in my code

Comment: For example : user want to touch  screen at position (20, 20) . 
I won't press (20, 20) on screen real , however I want to use (20, 20) as arguments to a function to make OS know I want to press (20, 20) then the APP will run the activity like I press (20, 20) .

Comment: i re- wrote your question please check and see if it suits your needs, or check if i have your best interest. to your question i will try to post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reference from the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836333/how-to-check-if-the-screen-hasnt-been-clicked-in-android/29836709#29836709) you can get the co-ordinates if the user touched the screen on your app. After you implement that on touch listener then in the `if` statement `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` put this there

```
 float myX = event.getX();
 float myY = event.getY();
 // now you can then pass myX,myY in your method or function as parameters
```

if you happen to be targeting `Api 14+` then you can use `onhover` with the same approach as to the first one from that post, instead of using `setOnTouchListener` use`getWindow().getDecorView().setOnHoverListener()` that's about it.

*A side note is using the firs one is better because onHover can not be trusted to work,actually it doesn't work to me, thats just btw*

hope i answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom view by extending android view and overriding onTouchEvent method. For example,

```
public class NotTouchableWebView extends WebView {
private Context context;

public NotTouchableWebView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context=context;
}

public NotTouchableWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context=context;
}

public NotTouchableWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    this.context=context;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public NotTouchableWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (some condition){
        //your specific function
        return false;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

}